# AngularJS is not linking through HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, angularjs

I already viewed questions related to this, my code is right as answered in previous question then also not working. Its very simple beginner code

```
<html ng-app="">
<head>
    <title>Assignment</title>
    <script src="‪js/angular.min.js" ></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .body{
                background-color: red
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Enter name <input type="text" ng-model="color" name=""><br>
    Name : {{color}}

</body>
</html>
```

output:
enter name : _______________
name : {{color}}
I am not getting the value that tried to store in color.

Comment: `ng-app=""` hasn't been supported in angularjs for a very long time.... how old is the tutorial you are trying to follow to create this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the correct code syntax and html structure. - especially wrapping the code within the `ng-app` and  `ng-controller`.

Note that you can apply background color as the person is typing - and this will change the background color of the body - but ONLY when the entered text matches a value that is a recognised color. Eg: "red" will make the background red, but if you delete that cahracter bey character and then type in "blue" the background will be white for when the word does not match a defined color - eg: red... re ... r ...b ..bl... blu... blue.

It would be better to use the `.blur()` method to change the background color when the user has finished typing - rather than the entered text on keystroke. You are still not guaranteed of a valid color thought - so it wouldbe best to use a select list and a defined set of options for the colors. Even then - I would assin a class with the required styling adn add / remove the class - eg: body.red { background-color: red}; body.blue { background-color: blue};

There are bettwe ways of changing the background color - but this demo will give you the basics on how to set up your angularJS app and how to reference the $scope variable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
   angular.module('DemoApp', [])
   .controller('DemoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.color = "red";
   }]);

  </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoController" ng-style="{'background-color': color}">

Enter name <input type="text" ng-model="color" name=""><br/>Name : {{color}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much buddy, i tried this code. it helped a lot to learn, I tried that online link as well, but  it also didn't worked. and that was something 1.8. I dont know whats the issue with it. But once again thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to have helped -thanks for accepting it -  Good luck with your coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I found some wired character in front of js/

```
<script src="‪js/angular.min.js" ></script>
```

it's make the angularjs import failed.

try to retype the url or use the official cdn.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.0/angular.min.js" ></script>
```